# Ckeditor custom plugin is not working

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to implement a timestamp example plugin given in the [www.ckeditor.com.](http://www.ckeditor.com) But this button is not showing up in my toolbar even though I followed all the steps given in their website such plugin name same as folder name,right place for plugin.js and image.And I added CKEditor.confi.extraplugins in config.js file and added name in toolbar in config.js.And in jsp page my code is

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor_source.js"></script>

window.onload = function(){                             
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{                               
fullPage : true,
extraPlugins :'docprops',
extraPlugins : 'timestamp',
toolbar : 'LISToobar' 
    });                                                         
    };
```

But some how timestamp button is not showing up in my toolbar.Please help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't define extraPlugins twice, you must add the plugins separated by commas:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ckeditor/ckeditor_source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){                             
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
{                               
fullPage : true,
extraPlugins :'docprops,timestamp',
toolbar : 'LISToobar' 
    });                                                         
};
</script>
```